# Участник 2 дней/месяцев

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[В профиле одного участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186316/denis-i) видел такой текст

> Участник 2 дней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понимаю грамматику, то должно быть

> Участник 2 дня

---

[Такая же проблема есть с месяцами тоже.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin)

Comment: Правильно понимаете. )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант перевода:

- Участник на протяжении 1, 21, 101 дня
- Участник на протяжении 2, 3, 4 дней
- Участник на протяжении 5, 10, 20 дней

Comment: я сам за этот вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант перевода:

- Участник 1, 21, 101 день
- Участник 2, 3, 4 дня
- Участник 5, 10, 20 дней

Answer (score 2):

Вариант перевода:

- 1 (21, 101) день с момента регистрации
- 2 (23, 1024) дня с момента регистрации
- 5 (7, 100) дней с момента регистрации

Недостаток: не очень благозвучно

Достоинство: перевод начинается с числа, будет лучше выглядеть в профиле

Comment: Кстати, отличная идея.

Comment: Может, тогда и последнее посещение с числа начать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Можно! Но как быть с «Последнее посещение вчера»?

Comment: Хм. Да, не выйдет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: ... а жаль!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант перевода:

- Участник в течение 1, 21, 101 дня
- Участник в течение 2, 3, 4 дней
- Участник в течение 5, 10, 20 дней

Comment: Почему дня/дней/дней, а не день/дня/дней?

Comment: Аа, вопрос снят, понял, это одного/двух/пяти, вместо один/два/пять, да?

Comment: @PeterOlson: да. В течение одного дня, двух дней.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Родительный падеж это, если что. Кстати, а как и где вы русский язык изучали?

Comment: Я один семестр учил математику в московском университете, и два года до этого жил несколько месяцев с друзьями в Украине.